# ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord

I am deploying a Rails project on heroku(using jruby).
It is being deployed successfully but I am not able to run:

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

(I am one of the collaborators of the app and not the owner)

It is throwing an exception:

`ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.163.178.100", user "XXXX", database "YYYY", SSL off`

After searching over I got one way i.e adding `?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` in DB url, but I am not sure where to add it.

Apart from all this when I try to deploy the same Rails project on my personal account's app it is working fine.`heroku run rake db:migrate` is getting succeeded.

Can someone please help me with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[External connections to Heroku Postgres require SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku). This isn't an issue of certificate validation. The problem is that you need to enable SSL.

Add

```
ssl=true
```

to [your JDBC parameters](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/ssl.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply Craig.Checked the first link which you sent. According to that it looks like we don't need to do anything if heroku app is using heroku postgres which is my case. So do we still need to set this property?
Is the connection between my app and heroku postgres is being considered as external connection?
Not getting the things, new to heroku and ROR, can you please explain?